# Какие есть способы перенести переменную в область видимости другой функции?

Tags: javascript

Собственно, лучше показать код, как можно заставить это работать?

```
function Test(){
  alert(myVar);
}

function Main(myFunct){
  var myVar = 123; // Все объявленные переменные должны перебраться в область видимости переданной функции. В PHP, например, это делается с помощью extract()
  myFunct();
}

Main(Test); // Передаем в Main некую функцию
```

Дело в том, что сейчас мне приходится обходится как-то так:

```
function Test(args){
  alert(args.tmyVart)
}

function Main(){
  Test({myVar: 123})
}

Main();
```

А это сильно уменьшает читаемость кода когда всюду стоят `args.`

Comment: а зачем передавать args, если можно так же передать `myVar`? В коде возможно опечатка, потому что в функции Main - `myVar`, в функции Test - `tmyVart`

Comment: Потому что в функцию может быть передано хз сколько аргументов, нужен аналог extract в php

Comment: как бы в этом случае использовалось _extract_ и чем это принципиально отличается от вариант с передачей параметром?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В ECMA2015 добавлена возможность использовать [реструктуризующее присваивание](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0_%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8) в параметрах функций.

Его можно использовать в следующем виде

```js
function Test({  myVar: tmyVart }) {
  console.log('Test func','Parameter tmyVart: ', tmyVart);
}

function Test2({ myVar }) {
  console.log('Test2 func','Parameter myVar: ', myVar);
}

function Main() {
  Test({ myVar: 123 });
  Test2({ myVar: 125 });
}

Main();
```

Answer (score 4):

Напиши так:

```js
function Main(){
  var myVar = 123;
  function Test(){
    alert(myVar);
  }
  Test();
}
```

У тебя переменная *myVar* объявляется внутри функции Main() и принадлежит объекту-контексту выполнения *Local* этой функции.

Когда интерпретатор заходит в функцию Test(), то переменной *myVar* в объекте-контексте выполнения этой функции нет. Значит, его надо ГДЕ-ТО искать. Интерпретатор идет в свойство *scope* объекта контекста выполнения функции Test() (он тоже *Local* называется), которое ссылается на объект-стек (тут объекты переменных VO (объекты переменных данного объекта-контекста и других объектов-контекстов) находятся и объекты *Closure*)и видит там объект *Closure*  и из него вытаскивает эту переменную *myVar*. Это - ЗАМЫКАНИЕ. Для этого и придумали замыкания. вкладываешь тело функции 2 в функцию 1 и тебе доступны переменные и параметры из функции 1 через замыкание - объект *Closure*.

То есть, ты можешь достать переменную из другой функции, как параметр (как ты сделал) или через замыкание.

Comment: А если функция Test передается в Main в качестве аргумента? (надо было сразу это упомянуть, черт, мой промах)

Comment: я запутался. исправь свой вопрос, чтобы понятно было, что куда передается

Comment: Готово, переправил вопрос

Answer (score 1):

Например следующим образом:

```
var sampleObject = {
    myVar: null,
    test: function() {
       alert(this.myVar);
    },
    main: function() {
       this.myVar = 123;
       this.test();
    }
}
sampleObject.main();
```

Comment: Как раз суть всего этого упростить читаемость кода, и не пользоваться бла_бла.myVar, а просто писать myVar

Comment: @Fangog если обращение к `this` для вас снижает читаемость кода - советую больше практиковаться в чтении кода!